# How to obtain the changed file names from the QFileSystemWatcher `directoryChanged` event

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qt-signals, qfilesystemwatcher

How can one obtain the changed file names from the QFileSystemWatcher `directoryChanged` event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect your slot to the `fileChanged()` signal instead of `directoryChanged()` if you are more interested in the file names.

```
connect(&myFileSystemWatcher, SIGNAL(fileChanged(const QString&)), SLOT(handleFileChanged(const QString&)));
```

Then, you can just use the slot argument as desired. Here, I am just printing it out to stdout:

```
void handleFileChanged(const QString &path)
{
    qDebug() << path;
}
```

Please see the documentation for further details:

> [void QFileSystemWatcher::fileChanged(const QString & path) [signal]](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html#fileChanged)
>
> This signal is emitted when the file at the specified path is modified, renamed or removed from disk.

Not sure how much you are familiar with the Qt signal/slot system, but if not enough, please go through this, too:

[Qt Signals & Slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Comment: As for add, modify and delete distinction, [this post](http://blog.rburchell.com/2012/01/qfilesystemwatcher-internals-in-qt-5.html) might be useful for the readers from Robin.